# PHP. How to get the access token. Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 for Google API

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token

[I found this function](http://www.jensbits.com/2011/12/20/authenticating-with-oauth-2-0-for-google-api-access-with-php/) that supposedly gets the accessToken, but I get nothing.
I do have the `$_REQUEST['code']`, and the other information needed in this function.

Any ideas what is wrong here?
Thanks.

```
//Oauth 2.0: exchange token for session token so multiple calls can be made to api
if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
    $_SESSION['accessToken'] = get_oauth2_token($_REQUEST['code']);
}

//returns session token for calls to API using oauth 2.0
function get_oauth2_token($code) {
    global $client_id;
    global $client_secret;
    global $redirect_uri;

    $oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    $clienttoken_post = array(
    "code" => $code,
    "client_id" => $client_id,
    "client_secret" => $client_secret,
    "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    );

    $curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $authObj = json_decode($json_response);

    if (isset($authObj->refresh_token)){
        //refresh token only granted on first authorization for offline access
        //save to db for future use (db saving not included in example)
        global $refreshToken;
        $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
    }

    $accessToken = $authObj->access_token;
    return $accessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but you may want to try refreshing the client secret and see if that helps.  Additionally, I would suggest you see exactly what the response is coming back from your curl command, I suspect it's "invalid_grant".

A much better way to do this is to use google's php api client:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

which handles most of the communication for you.  The examples there are very easy to use.  It mostly depends on which google service you are trying to access.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did to get my access token and refresh token.

Create a file that contains the following code :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // try to get an access token
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    $params = array(
        "code" => $code,
        "client_id" => YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret" => YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "redirect_uri" => 'http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'URL'), $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POST'), true);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POSTFIELDS'), $params);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($info['http_code'] === 200) {
        header('Content-Type: ' . $info['content_type']);
        return $output;
    } else {
        return 'An error happened';
    }
} else {

    $url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";

    $params = array(
        "response_type" => "code",
        "client_id" => YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
        "redirect_uri" => 'http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],
        "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
    );

    $request_to = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params);

    header("Location: " . $request_to);
}
```

Now, replace `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` and `YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET` with your client ID and client secret.

Make sure your scope is correct. For example, it should be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics` if you want to get access to Analytics.

If you run the file, you should get an OAuth2 approval screen.

If you now press `Accept`, you should get a result that looks like this:

```
{
  "access_token" : YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN
}
```

The result may contain additional fields, depending on which scope you're applying for.

Comment: How did you run the file? I put it into a php file on filezilla and executed with the browser. But it doesn't work for me

Comment: @John Slegers 
all working fine in my case except I didn't get the refresh_token

Comment: how do i get only access_token and not other fields like bearer or scope

Answer (score 1):

that code looks familiar - I'm using roughly the same code - there are two things you can try.

1. Use echo to echo the response to the Browser

   echo $json_response;
2. Get hold of Fiddler and use the following line before the call to curl_exec

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');

'fraid I've not got it working either - the response I am getting is

```
{ 
     "error" : "invalid_request" 
}
```

Now if anyone knows how what is wrong with this ;)

Answer (score 0):

From section 4.4.2 of "The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Protocol draft-ietf-oauth-v2-20"

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by adding the
>      following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>      format in the HTTP request entity-body:

So the POSTed parameters should be submitted in the form of a string, not an array. This is mentioned in the PHP manual for curl_setopt too.

So instead of posting $clienttoken_post, you might want to post http_build_query($clienttoken_post,'','&').

This might not solve all your problems, but it's probably a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and I found that adding

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

to allow the request follow a redirect solved it quickly.  I hope that helps someone else!